# AIC formula in R vs Python

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, aic

I have been trying to calculate a GLM's AIC both in python (package Statsmodels) and R (native glm function). For exactly the same model I get two different AIC estimates. The formula for AIC is:

-2 * log-likelihood + 2*n<sub>pars</sub>,

where n<sub>pars</sub> is the number of model parameters to be estimated.
My understanding is that R includes the variance of error as an estimated parameter but Statsmodels in python ([source](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.html#RegressionResults.aic)) doesn't, thus having one less parameter in the formula. Is this a bug or am I missing something fundamental here? To make it more general, should the variance of errors be included as a parameter when calculating the AIC?

Comment: Could it be that the differences are du to the optimizer being used, not the parameters being estimated?

Comment: @ Skander H. Both functions use the Gaussian family as default but I can't really tell if there are any differences in the optimisation

Comment: Likelihoods are defined only up to a multiplicative constant, thereby permitting different software to report different likelihood values for the same data.  As far as your second question goes, it's hard to see how one might answer it since in most GLMs the "variance of errors" does not appear in the expression for the AIC at all.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. Regarding the error variance I was pretty sure that it shows in the basic likelihood function of the linear model (the σ2 term). Am I wrong?

Comment: You would be correct only for a GLM with a Gaussian response distribution.  There isn't any such term, for instance, in a logistic regression--it wouldn't make any sense.